# Akka / Actors: Share a single, limited resource among the actor hierarchy

Tags: akka, actor

I'm learning Akka, and I'm struggling to find a good pattern to share a single, limited resource among the whole actor hierarchy.

My use case is that I have a HTTP REST endpoint to which I'm only allowed 10 simultaneous connections at any time. Different actors at different levels of the hierarchy need to be able to make HTTP REST calls. I'm using non-blocking I/O to make the HTTP requests (AsyncHttpClient).

The obvious solution is to have a single actor in charge of this REST resource, and have any actors who want to access it send a message to it and expect a reply at a later stage, however:

- Having a single actor in charge of this resource feels a bit fragile to me
- How should any "client" actor know how to reach this resource manager actor? Is it best to create it at a well known location like `/user/rest-manager` and use an actor selection, or is it better to try to pass its `ActorRef` to every actor that needs it (but meaning it will need to be passed down in a lot of actors that don't use it, just so they can in turn pass it down)

In addition, how to deal with "blocking" the client actors when 10 connections are already in progress, especially since I'm using non-blocking I/O? Is it best practice to re-send a message to `self` (perhaps after some time) as a wait pattern?

I also thought of a token-based approach where the resource manager actor could reply with "access tokens" to client actors that needs to access the resource until exhaustion. However it means that client actors are supposed to "return" the token once they're done which doesn't sound ideal, and I will also need cater for actors dying without returning the token (with some sort of expiration timeout I guess).

What are the patterns / best practices to deal with that situation?

*Updated: To indicate I'm using non-blocking I/O*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions would be:

- Use the **Error Kernel** pattern, as the REST endpoint, as you said, is a fragile code (I/O operations can generate any kind of errors). In other words, **Master/Worker** actor hierarchy, where Workers do the job, while Master does any supervision
- Connection limit could be handled by Akka **Routing** feature, where number of Routees is, in your case, 10. This also drops into Master/Worker category
- Addressing - either way sounds good
- Connection timeout - to be handled by a client code, as it's always done in a majority of network libs.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I should have mentioned I'm using non-blocking I/O for the HTTP requests (question updated) which I think will prevent me from using routing as the 10 routees won't "block" while they're making a REST request?

Comment: Ok, here is the idea. Stick to Routing. Your Rest client has to have some kind of callback mechanism to notify when Rest response is ready. When a `Routee` receives `RestRequest` message from a `Master` it tells a Rest client to process it with a `onCompleted` callback which sends the response to self (`self ! RequestCompleted(response)`). When waiting for a `RequestCompleted` message Routee moves (`become(..)`) to `waitingForResponse` mode until the response is received. All other RestRequest messages from `Master` can be stashed until back to `ready` mode.